# Not able to select return 1 of 1 powershell script

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm writing a pseudo-search engine for a company for them to find some songs and then select them and do stuff with them. I am able to display and select the content just fine until the return gives me only one song. And when you try to select that one song the error that is returned is:

```
Unable to index into an object of type System.IO.FileInfo.
At C:\Users\adammcgurk\Documents\WorkOnSearch.ps1:83 char:20
+$Selected = $Items[ <<<< $Input - 1]
  + CategoryInfo              : InvalidOperation: (0:Int32) [], RuntimeException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId     : CannotIndex
```

Here is the part of the code in question:

```
$SearchInput = Read-Host "Enter song name here:"
$Items = Get-ChildItem C:\Users\adammcgurk\Desktop\Songs -Recurse -Filter *$SearchInput*
$Index = 1
$Count = $Items.Count
foreach ($Item in $Items) {
    $Item | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Index" -Value $Index
    $Index++
}
$Items | Select-Object Index, Name | Out-Host
$Input = Read-Host "Select an item by index number (1 to $Count)"
$Selected = $Items[$Input - 1]
Write-Host "You have selected $Selected"
```

The ultimate goal is to be able to select the single song when only one is returned. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of observations, you are using $input as a variable name, but this is an automatic variable that is not being used correctly. (get-help about_automatic_variables) Change the name of the variable.

The other issue is that $Items may or may not be an array but you are attempting to index it either way. You can either explicitly cast $Items to be an array at creation

```
#This will ensure that the return value is an array regardless of the number of results
$Items = @(Get-ChildItem C:\Users\adammcgurk\Desktop\Songs -Recurse -Filter *$SearchInput*)
```

Or you could check $items before asking

```
if($Items -is [System.Array]){
    #Handle choice selection
}else{
    #only one object
    $Items
}
```

I'd also be careful about using Write-Host. You can dig down the rabbit hole if you look it up but usually Write-Host is not the output choice you should use.

Comment: Thank you! I decided to check $Items and it works now! I also changed the variable